# having trouble getting user authorization variables working

Tags: node.js, header, authorization, token

In am having trouble passing the token information to my controller for authorization. In the below code, I have console logged the relevant information and I am able to get the token correctly, and the decoded information, but not the req.user information. When I console.log for that information I receive null, and when I console.log for decoded.id, I get undefined. I believe this is what is hanging up my authorization, however I'm not sure what to look at to fix it? Any thoughts very helpful!
Here's a github link:https://github.com/roxanneweber/projectmanager

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');

const User = require('../models/userModel');

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let token;

    if (
        req.headers.authorization &&
        req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
    ) {
        try {
            // Get token from header
            token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
            console.log(token);
            // Verify token
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            console.log(decoded);
            // Get user from token
            req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password');
            console.log(req.user);
            console.log(decoded.id);

            next();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(401);
            throw new Error('Not authorized');
        }
    }

    if (!token) {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error('Not authorized');
    }
});

module.exports = { protect };
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i am handling the token like this in my auth.middleware.ts

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    // add userData object to request
    req.userData = {
      email: decodedToken.email,
      userId: decodedToken.userId,
      username: decodedToken.username,
      role: decodedToken.role,
    };
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'not authenticated',
    });
  }
}
```

then my frontend handles setting the token like this:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

export interface HttpConfig {
  body?: any;
  headers?: HttpHeaders;
  observe?: any;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
    const authRequest = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken),
    });
    return next.handle(authRequest);
  }
}
```

then i am using the auth.middleware.ts in my backend route files like this:

```
import express from 'express';
import authMiddleware from '../middleware/auth.middleware';
import FooController from './foo.controller';

class FooRoutes {
  router = express.Router();
  fooController = FooController;

  constructor() {
    this.configureRoutes();
  }

  configureRoutes() {
    this.router.post('/foo/start', authMiddleware, this.fooController.start);
    this.router.put('/foo/stop/:id', authMiddleware, this.fooController.stop);
    this.router.get('/foo/:userId', authMiddleware, this.fooController.getAll);
    this.router.delete('/foo/delete/:id', authMiddleware, this.fooController.delete);
  }
}

export default new FooRoutes().router;
```